# Implementing UPI Payments in Flutter: Handling Google Pay Intent in iOS

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, url-launcher

I am currently working on a Flutter app that involves UPI (Unified Payments Interface) payments. In the Android part of the app, I've successfully implemented UPI payments using method channels. I've created native Kotlin code to handle the intent for Google Pay and check the activity result for the payment response.

Now, I'm facing a challenge with the iOS implementation. I need guidance on how to handle UPI payments in Flutter for iOS, specifically for Google Pay. I'm not sure how to create an equivalent mechanism in Swift for opening Google Pay and capturing the payment response.

Here is a simplified version of the Android code I used:

```
    private fun makeGooglePayTransaction(
        merchantVpa: String,
        merchantName: String,
        merchantCode: String,
        transactionRefId: String,
        transactionNote: String,
        orderAmount: String
    ) {
        val GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user"
        val GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123

        val uri = Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("upi")
            .authority("pay")
            .appendQueryParameter("pa", merchantVpa)
            .appendQueryParameter("pn", merchantName)
            .appendQueryParameter("mc", merchantCode)
            .appendQueryParameter("tr", transactionRefId)
            .appendQueryParameter("tn", transactionNote)
            .appendQueryParameter("am", orderAmount)
            .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
            .build()

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = uri
        intent.`package` = GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME

        startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE)

    }
```

I am seeking advice on how to achieve a similar functionality in Flutter for iOS using Swift. I want to open Google Pay and handle the payment response. Any insights, code snippets, or references would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried this package => https://pub.dev/packages/pay?

Comment: yes ,but with that package i think we can only implement transaction with cards . and most of the upi packages in pub.dev  is only for android and some of them are not returning proper response .

Comment: @AbduSaleem, what are you passing for merchantCode ? how to get it ?

Comment: merchent code is a identifier provided by google pay when we create a google pay merchent account for buisness purpos